# (Replication) System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name'

Tags: c#, winforms, replication

I encounter this error while trying to load data from a subscription

Subscription's articles:

[Subscription's articles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUjEu.png)

Error:

[Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEvMF.png)

Translation:

In table SINHVIEN(Student) there are columns include MASV(student ID), HO(last name), TEN(first name), MALOP(Class ID, Foreign Key), DANGHIHOC(Dropped out)

Columns: PHAI(sex), DIACHI(address), NGAYSINH(date of birth), PASSWORD from subscription database aren't exist due to replication.

How can I solve this error? I think i should add a new Dataset from subscription but is there any better method?

Comment: You have to show your Select statement from the adapter

Comment: The Dataset I currently using is from Publisher. So the statement Select contains every columns from Publisher's table. "SELECT MASV, HO, TEN, PHAI, DIACHI, NGAYSINH, MALOP, DANGHIHOC, PASSWORD FROM SINHVIEN"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have some columns you have to try to change the select statement

Try this

```
SELECT MASV, HO, TEN, MALOP, DANGHIHOC FROM SINHVIEN
```